# Add some money to my current money in React

Tags: reactjs, crud

I have an app with some axios responses, like post, get, etc, and I have a component with a kind of credit card interface, when I add some money to input and then click on "add money" button I should update my current money on account with this new money, not replace, just add this money to my current money on my database, I have this code, Im newbie at React, so any help would be nice.

```
export default class PaymentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.handleInputFocus = this.handleInputFocus.bind(this);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeMoney = this.onChangeMoney.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    
        this.state = {
            cvc: '',
            expiry: '',
            focus: '',
            name: '',
            number: '',
            money: '',
        };
      }
    


  handleInputFocus = (e) => {
    this.setState({ focus: e.target.name });
  }
  onChangeMoney(e) {
    this.setState({ money: e.target.value });
  }
  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    const userObject = {
      money: this.state.money,
    };
    let url = window.location.href;
    url = url.replace("http://localhost:3000/wallet/", "");
    let _id = url;
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:5000/profile/wallet/${_id}`, userObject)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.setState({ money: "", });
  }
  
  
  render() {
.....
```

Comment: where do you update the money ?

Answer (score 0):

You must understand Promise.
SetState move to then callback

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add money to the current money, you would need to do something like this :

- get the money from the database (this.state.money)
- set a variable with the new money and bind it to the input (this.state.currentMoney)
- when you do your axios.put, you send in the body of the request, the sum of the current money and the money written in the input (this.state.money + this.state.currentMoney)

```
this.state = {
            cvc: '',
            expiry: '',
            focus: '',
            name: '',
            number: '',
            money: '',
            currentMoney: '',
};

onChangeMoney(e) {
    this.setState({ inputMoney: e.target.value });
}

const userObject = {
      money: this.state.money + this.state.inputMoney,
    };
```

Comment: Could you write a little more code? cuz I still cant understand, thank u so much